# Windows 10 does not install GTX 1060 video card driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

In Device Manager my MSI GTX 1060 3GB is displayed as "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter":

[image]

When I try to update driver I get this:

[image]

GPUZ shows this:

[image]

My monitor is connected to on-board Intel video output.

The card worked on some other Windows 10 machine and on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [msi.com](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-Card/support/GeForce-GTX-1060-GAMING-X-3G#support-main-block-download) you should download and install [GeForce Experience.](https://www.nvidia.com/nl-nl/geforce/geforce-experience/) It will keep your drivers up to date and the games optimized.

Another option is the manual install on the MSI page (I wouldn't recommend that in this case).